# Spring boot, Angular, Dealing with a User entered URL (Circular view path error)

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Having looked for a while I can't seem to find an obvious answer about how to redirect users to the correct page if for example they were to enter http://myapp.com/randompath, as it would be annoying to have to traverse the whole app manually if they already knew what page they wanted to visit for example.

Eg. in spring boot I have tried mapping a normal controller to "/**/*", with the idea of always returning the index page then using js on client side to resolve the URL path and redirect to the right page within the single page app on load, or maybe adding attributes to the model to also check for and redirect on load, but it throws a "Circular view path exception" error when using this RequestMapping.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/**/*")
public class IndexController{

    public static final String INDEX_PAGE = "index";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHomePage(ModelMap model){
        return INDEX_PAGE;
    }

}
```

I have set application properties as such:

```
spring.view.prefix=
spring.view.suffix=.html
```

Which does return the correct page if I set the RequestMapping to just "/" instead. So I was wondering how to resolve this circular view error and if there is a different way of handling this use case with spring boot and angular in a more correct way?

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies thus far, but is there not a common method that people use in angular applications for users returning to a url inside the application instead of the root?
I am considering defining the index controller method as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/", "/examplepath1", "/examplepath2/**", ...})
```

Then using the window.location.href on load in js to forward to the correct page, but this seems a bit excessive and something that could potentially get very messy in a large app for example, having to account for every new path in the app in this way. Maybe I'm misunderstanding some core principle somewhere (first time delving into using spring with angular) but it does seem like a common use case that I'm struggling to allow for.

Thanks

Comment: Something like that might make some sense (but see below), but surely you have static resources you want to serve as well, and any modular angular app will have templates it wants to load, so you have to be able to serve things that are not index.html.

Comment: @Dave You're right. I think I may have answered in haste and didn't really think through what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Most people writing angular apps use static resources AFAIK, so there's no need for a controller.